# Sum days for multiple date ranges in one table

Tags: sql-server

I need to count days between multiple date ranges from one table.

TABLE

| ID | transdate | statuscode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6/24/2021 | OPEN |
| 2 | 11/17/2021 | CLOSED |
| 3 | 12/21/2021 | OPEN |

Days between first OPEN and CLOSED = 146
Days between second OPEN and @Today = 30
For a total of 176.

And there could be multiple Open & Closed sets.

Comment: Is that how transdate is actually stored, or do you have it a more reasonable way (ie: datetime or date column?). I say "more reasonable", but it looks like varchar, and varchar is **NOT** a reasonable way to store dates.

Comment: Also: I suggest searching for "gaps and islands". Regardless of how the date is formatted, this is ultimately a gaps and islands problem... but it's one of those things I just can't keep in my head for some reason, so I have to look it up every time, too.

Comment: It would be better to have a slightly wider data sample and the corresponding desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try following Code:**

```
declare @MyTbl table
(
ID int, transdate date, statuscode nvarchar(50)
)

insert into @MyTbl (ID, transdate, statuscode) values (1,CAST(N'6/24/2021' as Date), N'OPEN')
insert into @MyTbl (ID, transdate, statuscode) values (2,CAST(N'11/17/2021' as Date), N'CLOSED')
insert into @MyTbl (ID, transdate, statuscode) values (3,CAST(N'12/21/2021' as Date), N'OPEN')


select  Sum(DATEDIFF(DAY, D.transdate , D.NextDate)) as SumOfDiffDates from (
select ID, transdate, statuscode , 
case when statuscode = N'OPEN' and (ID <> (select MAX(ID) as MaxIDs from @MyTbl)) 
     then (LEAD(transdate) over (order by ID)) 
     else  (case when statuscode = N'OPEN' and (ID = (select MAX(ID) as MaxIDs from @MyTbl)) then cast(getdate() as date) else null end) 
     end as NextDate from @MyTbl
) as D where D.NextDate is not null
```

[image: Result]

This query can be used for any number of records. I wrote the bet dynamically so that any number of records entered would give the correct answer.

Comment: This works perfectly.   I was able to incorporate it in my code.